# Nativescript 6 - detect if the app is in debug or production mode

Tags: nativescript

Is the a way, at run time, to detect if the app is running in debug or production (release) mode.

I have multiple settings that vary between the 2 modes and I want to preload them  when the app starts.

I was looking at https://github.com/markosko/nativescript-hook-debug-production, but this plugin has not been updated in 3 years and I am not sure if it is compatible with NS 6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Webpack](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack) to pass environment variables and use them to identify your build type.

For example,

```
tns build [ios|android] --env.prod
```

The `prod` flag may tell whether this is production build, you may update the `DefinePlugin` settings in `webpack.config.js` to inject the value

```
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ...
            "global.isProduction": env.prod
        }),
```

Now in your code you may access `global.isProduction`

Comment: Thank you Manoj,  I followed your suggestion, but global.isProduction comes back as undefined.

Comment: Is it undefined even when you pass the variable in command line? Did you try to add logs to web pack config see if you are getting the value in there?

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, check the `TNS_ENV` variable.

e.g.

```
if (TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
  // dev only operation
}
```